# How to iterate a template for a component in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chess

What I would like to do is a simple chess app.
I created a component named *Piece* and a component named *Player*.
Now there are two instances of Player (player1 and player2) and each one has an array of 16 Piece.

The component Piece has a template: `<app-piece>`.
Now, I would like to iterate the `<app-piece>` for each piece type (king, queen...) of the player.

In my main view I have something like

```
<div id='chessboard'>
   //@For each player1.pieces as piece
       <app-piece [@something that labels uniquely this tag]="{{piece.id}}">
       </app-piece>
</div>
```

And in my `piece.component` template I have something like

```
<div id={{specific_instance_of_the_piece.id}}>
     {{specific_instance_of_the_piece.name}}
</div>
```

What I would like to get is something like

```
<div id='chessboard>
    <div id='1'>King</div>
    <div id='2'>Queen</div>
</div>
```

How could this be done in Angular?

Comment: i dont follow your question, it sounds like youre asking to do something that you have already done?

Comment: This can help you? Use @Input and Output properties : https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#inputs-outputs

Comment: @mast3rd3mon,you're right. The problem is that i don't know how to replace the rows beginning with @.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<div id="chessboard">
  <app-piece *ngFor="let piece of player1.pieces; let i = index" [id]="i">
      {{piece.name}}
  </app-piece>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but i would like to ngFor just the <piece></piece> and to write the informations (like the item name) into the component template. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: you could put the ngfor on a div and have the `app-piece` within the div?

Comment: Yes, @mast3rd3mon. But then how could i call the specific instance of the piece from piece.component.html?

I mean: I would like to keep the main template with just an empty <app-piece></app-piece> and then fill it from the component template.

Comment: @stronzio90 you could use an id assigned via the array of pieces, this way you can get the specific piece via its id

Comment: @stronzio90  what do you need the id for?